# How to make a listbox in c# not duplicate items on button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

Well, i'm using ASP.NET c# listbox. I also have a button, the idea is the following: whenever I click the button an item x has to be shown in the listbox. However, I click the button many times, and instead of replacing the x value in the list for the new value (pretend it's y), it shows the following:
x
y

The expected result would be:
y

I mean, i don't want values to be on top of eachother, just one at a time.

Comment: So you want to empty the listbox on each click and then add the 'one' selected item everytime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be having a code behind file where the selected items (selected by clicking the button) should be getting added to the listBox object.

When you run a loop to add items to this listBox object, use the `Contains` method to check if the listBox object already contains the current item. Add only if it does not contain.

Answer (score 0):

At code behind : 
Before that you need to create list and store all the listbox value. if listbox doesn't have value then keep list as null.

Every time you need to check whether the list contain the value or not if list contain value then you don't need to add, if not contain then you need to add.

in Jquery :

on button click first get all the listbox list item value and check that in that list whether that list contain the value or not which you want to add.

May be this is help full for you.